# Isolated Storage is not replacing new values? app breaks?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was using IsolatedStorage for saving the integer from the user. To add the first integer, it works well. Given integer is added successfully.

But, while giving another integer to be saved on the same string (to replace old integer)using IsolatedStorage `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key"] = site;` , App breaks.

here my code:

```
        int num = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(txtbox.Text, out num) && num > 0)
        {
            string site;
            site = num.ToString();
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Key", site);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key"] = site;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Bookmark created successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TextBox is not supposed to be empty");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this line:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Key", site);
```

If you already have a setting called `Key`, that line will throw an exception, [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> **Exceptions:**
>   `ArgumentException` - `key` already exists in the dictionary.

... whereas this line:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key"] = site;
```

just *replaces* any previous value.

You should take a step back to work out why you couldn't spot this for yourself though: you say that the application "breaks" - presumably an exception is thrown, and you should make sure you're able to get the stack trace (and message) for any exceptions. That should pinpoint where the problem is. It's very important to be able to see any exceptions thrown by your app, as otherwise diagnosing problems can be incredibly hard.